# GCP - Failed to load service accounts on restored account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I just restored an account I had attempted to delete last week, and when I restored it the only resource in it (Oauth credentials) were not restored, and when I try to create new ones, or even just navigate to the page, I get the following error.

`Failed to load service accounts`

Is there a way to get my Oauth Credentials and/or the ability to create new ones back in this project?

Comment: Hi, Google Cloud Support here, I'd like to take a further look to this.  
Could you open a private issue, an add your project number: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164
 Once we find the solution I will post it so the community can have the answer online as well.

Comment: Hi again Robert, when you've created the private issue please provide the ID (or URL) here so I can check it.

Comment: Hi Paula, thanks for the response. As I was putting in the ticket, I went to check the error I get and I see that this issue magically resolved itself. My keys are there, and the credentials page no longer gives me an error when navigating to it. Do you still want the private issue to debug?

Comment: Hi Robert, since it is working fine now we can leave it as it is because I won't be able to reproduce it, and this could have been a temporary issue that has been fixed. If you experience this behavior again, do not hesitate to write back here and I'll be happy to check it.

Comment: @Paula I am currently having this same issue.

Comment: @Paula I am also facing the same issue now

Comment: I am having this problem right now. Anyone find a solution?

Comment: Enabling App Engine Admin API solves issue for me (APIs & Services > Library > Search for App Engine Admin API > Enable)